# ASCII Art , nested loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, nested, ascii

I am trying to create some ASCII art in java using the code below.
The triangle should be as follows, this method should work for any number of inputted integer.
The triangle below is for an input of 3.

```
  *
 ***
*****
```

This is my attempt.

```
public static void triangle(int n){
for (int i=n;i>0;i--){//number of lines
    for(int j=i-1;j>0;j--){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for(int k=n;k>i;k--){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem? What output does your code generate so far?

Comment: USE `for(int k=n; k >= i ;k--)`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public static void triangle(int n){
for (int i=n;i>0;i--){//number of lines
   for(int j=i-1;j>0;j--){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for(int k=n;k>=i;k--){        //use k>=i
        System.out.print("*");
    }
System.out.print("\n");
}
```